# Using 2 different ISP In case one dies

Tags: routing, router, internet

It's my first ever post in here and I hope not the last. I'm looking for some advice. **I'm trying to reduce my internet downtime for a local network.**

**My setup.**

Mix and match computer environment (windows, Mac, Linux)  25+ users

**What I have**

- 2 different ISP or 2 different internet providers
- 2 different routers from ISP
- Smart switch ZyXEL GS1900 GS1920 series

Example: 
If in case one of my ISP having an issue with the internet ( I would like to do something which smartly changes the connection to 2nd ISP without downtime or physically changing the connection ) at the moment I have to change them manually which is pain and takes lot's of time in an intense situation. after changing to 2nd ISP I have to manually restart network adapter in all machines (Windows, Linux)

Is there anything I can set up which will help me to reduce downtime and all other things I do after changing.

Many Thanks

**Mahi**

Comment: You have tagged this Cisco, so do you have Cisco routers, and are you able to configure them? We really need a better network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. If you have Cisco routers (and you have access to them), you can configure HSRP (or VRRP) so they act as a single default gateway.  Some other brands may have similar features, but you will need administrative access to the routers to configure it.  If you don't have access then:
2. You need to buy another router that will select which ISP router to use.  This needs to be a commercial-grade router that can support HSRP and IP SLA (These are Cisco features, but other commercial routers have similar ones).  We can help you configure the router.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something called **Dual WAN** or **WAN failover**. This is a feature of some routers that will allow the router to automatically switch between the two different Internet connections. This all takes place on the router; your users would not need to change any settings when the router switched to the other ISP.

In your case, the ISP provided routers almost definitely will not have dual WAN, so you'll probably need to get your own business-grade router.

Comment: Thanks for your input Andrew.

Yes, you are right both of my ISP has provided me with 2 different routers and only one supports DUAL WAN Failover.

Answer (score 0):

The optimised and one  of the option is ..

If router is perimeter device in your setup means ..

==>  Configure floating static routes in router pointing towards ISP gateway ..

**For example consider gateways ISP**

`ISP 1 = gateway = 203.56.78.54`

`ISP2 = gateway = 156.78.43.78`

Local intranet private subnet = 10.0.0.0

Configure Floating static routes in perimeter router

`IP route destination 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 pointing` `towards ISP gateway 1 203.56.78.54 (AD value =1)`

`IP route destination 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0` pointing`towards ISP gateway 1 156.78.53.78 (AD value` `=2)`

Both ISP workload will be in Active and passive mode

**Traffic will flow from ISP 1 as AD value for ISP is set as 1 lower than ISP 2 . If ISP1 goes down then traffic will diverted to ISP2**